# How to make view to show from 2 tables as 1 table with rows as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.objects
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('objects_id_seq'::regclass),
  value text,
  CONSTRAINT objects_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE public.relation
(
  id1 bigint,
  id2 bigint,
  multiplier integer
);
```

The objects table stores data about any object and the relation tables stores relationships between objects through their ids, and multiplier is data about relationship.

Please help to make request to show this as simple table with objects as columns and rows and multiplier as values of relationships (column and row)

Like this

[image: Comps and Products like objects and values like multiplier]

Comps and Products as objects and values as multiplier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add some sample values as well.

Comment: @FahadAnjum pls. I add samples as 2 pictures.

Comment: You can check crosstab function in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

@Fahad Anjum thanx....

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('select o.value, o1.value, r.multiplier::text FROM objects as o, objects as o1, relation as r 
    where 
        o.id=r.id1 and
        o1.id = r.id2')
    AS ct(com text, P1 text, P2 text, P3 text);
```

It's work...